# Why doesn't Python instance variable work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, instance

Why doesn't the instance variable *b* work:

```
class Clothing:
    a = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0

shirt = Clothing
shirt.b
```

> AttributeError: type object 'Clothing' has no attribute 'b'

Why does trying to access *shirt.b* throw an Attribute error?

Comment: Instantiate class. `shirt = Clothing()`

Answer (score 3):

you need parentheses, it should be `shirt = Clothing()`

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
class Clothing:
   a = 5

   def __init__(self):
      self.b = 0

shirt = Clothing() # add the '()' here
shirt.b
print(shirt.b) #prints 0
```